# What kind of object is this, reactive?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code in my Server.R :

```
selection1 <- reactive({filter(filter(DF1, PC %in% input$dynamic),
                   AGE >= input$age[1] & AGE <= input$age[2])})
```

`DF1` is a data frame object of course, `input$dynamic` is a checkboxGroupInput and `input$age` is a slider input. But what kind of object is `selection1`? Is it a data frame too ?

Then I would have liked to count the number of unique occurrences in variable `COMMUN` in `selection1`, so I tried this :

```
selection2 <- length(unique(selection1$COMMUN))
```

But I have this error message :

> Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

How can I do this operation please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selection1` is a `reactive` function. In Shiny this means it is a function that holds/caches your data. The data it holds is updated when you call the function AND when the inputs to it change. If the inputs haven't changed when you call it, it returns the cached data.

To access the data you need to call the function itself using `selection1()`, and then follow this with the usual functions/code for subsetting the data. So in your case it would be

```
selection2 <- length(unique(selection1()$COLUMN))
```

The error you're seeing is the standard error when you try to perform the `$` operation on a function, without calling the function using `()`

```
foo <- function(){
    bar = data.frame(bar = c(1,2,3))
}

foo$bar
Error in foo$bar : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

foo()$bar
[1] 1 2 3
```

---

If you want to go into the actual detail of the structure of a `reactive` object, just call `str` on it and take a look

```
foo <- reactive()

str(foo)

function ()  
 - attr(*, "observable")=Classes 'Observable', 'R6' <Observable>
  Public:
    .dependents: environment
    .domain: NULL
    .error: FALSE
    .execCount: 0
    .func: function (...) 
    .invalidated: TRUE
    .label: foo
    .mostRecentCtxId: 
    .running: FALSE
    .updateValue: function () 
    .value: NULL
    .visible: 
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    getValue: function () 
    initialize: function (func, label = deparse(substitute(func)), domain = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), 
    self: Observable, R6 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "reactive"
```

Comment: Hi SymbolixAU, thanks much for answering, I understand better now. Just one more question please : I have to filter selection1 on the variable PC == "01". Is it possible to use the selection1 filter with selection2 length/unique criterions in the same line to have a shorter code ? I didn't manage to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Mickey_NC - I don't understand what you're asking. Do you mean `selection1()[ PC == "01", "COLUMN"]` ?

Comment: I have to filter selection1 on variable PC = "01", and then get the length(unique(selection1$COMMUN)) and I would like, if it's possible, doing these "filter" + "length/unique" instructions in the same line (selection2 <-) to get shorter code, as I will have to check if PC = "01" to "33" are present in selection1. Hope it's understandable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mickey_NC - in that case `length(unique(selection1()[ selection1()$PC == "01", "COLUMN"]))` should work?

Comment: So great ! Thank you very much SymbolixAU for these explanations and for your last suggestion which works perfectly. Have a very nice day.

Comment: @Mickey_NC you're welcome. Note that the way to access the data in a reactive function is the same as the standard way to access a `data.frame`'s data, you just need to use the `()` at the end of it, as it is still a function.

Comment: It would be amazing to see a small edit for how to actually coerce a reactive's contents to a data.frame.  In fact, I am not even able to `> foo <- reactive()
Error in eval(call("function", args, body), env) : 
  argument "expr" is missing, with no default`